# Como apresentar diferentes listas de categorias em uma mesma pagina usando Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

Bom dia, estou usando o Laravel 5.3, e preciso montar uma pagina com uma lista de categorias, e cada categoria é um dropdown que deve apresentar o link para os produtos dessas categorias, exemplo de como deve ficar:

> Categoria 1

- Produto 1A
- Produto 1B

> Categoria 2

- Produto 2A
- Produto 2B

> Categoria 3

- Produto 3A
- Produto 3B

Tudo isso são informações vindas do banco, o problema é que todas as categorias estão apresentando todos os produtos, esta ficando assim:

> Categoria 1

- Produto 1A
- Produto 1B
- Produto 2A
- Produto 2B
- Produto 3A
- Produto 3B

> Categoria 2

- Produto 1A
- Produto 1B
- Produto 2A
- Produto 2B
- Produto 3A
- Produto 3B

> Categoria 3

- Produto 1A
- Produto 1B
- Produto 2A
- Produto 2B
- Produto 3A
- Produto 3B

Por enquanto a view esta assim:

```
 @foreach($categorias as $key => $value)
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{$value->nome}}</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-produto" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
          @foreach($produtos as $key => $value)
            <li class=""><a href="{{url('produtos/'.$value->url.'/')}}" class="btn btn-primary">{{$value->nome}}</a></li>
          @endforeach
       </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

E o `controller` assim:

```
$data['categorias'] = Categorias::All();

$data['categorias'] = (
    Categorias::where('nome', 'like', "%%")
    ->orderBy('nome', 'asc')
    ->paginate(10)
);

$data['produtos'] = Produtos::All();

$data['produtos'] = (
     Produtos::where('nome', 'like', '%%')
      ->where('hidden', 'like', 0)
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
      ->paginate(10)
);        


return view('front/produtos/index', $data);
```

Comment: poste o layout das tabelas, poste o código que fez até o momento!

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você vai utilizar o `GroupBy` para resolver isso. Não estou falando do `GroupBy` do Query Builder do Eloquent, e sim do `Collection` (o resultado da sua consulta).

Exemplo:

```
$produtos = Produto::get(); // já pegou o resultado

$grupoProdutos = $produtos->groupBy(function ($produto) {
     // pega a penúltima letra e agrupa por elas
     return substr($produto->nome, -2, 1); 
});
```

Na view você pode fazer:

```
@foreach($grupoProdutos as $produtos)
    <select>
    @foreach($produtos as $produto)
        <!-- <option></option> -->
    @endforeach
    </select>
@endforeach
```